# Which function does WP use to format the output?

Tags: wordpress

I pulling a post's content using database query and printing it out.
Unfortunately, I am loosing all the formatting that WP puts in when outputting content.  Such as the additional br tags.  Which function does WP use to format the output? I would like to put the content through that function before printing it.  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the WordPress environment loaded, you should use

```
$formatted_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $raw_content );
```

That will apply every function WP normally uses on `the_content`

Otherwise, have a look at the functions wptexturize, wpautop, and others at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/formatting.php

Comment: +1 This is the way to go, *especially* if you use shortcodes.